# Deflection of an electron from a charged wire and from an interference grid: In both cases the electron radiates?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, interference

Near a charged wire a moving electron is deflected. Since the deflection is an acceleration, the electrons emit photons.

What about an electron's radiation, which is affected by an interference grating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since the deflection is an acceleration, the electrons emit photons.

Not in quantum mechanics/quantum field teory, emission is not *obligatory*, as it is in classical electrodynamics, when there is a dp/dt. It is an interaction between a particle and another particle, as is the case in diffraction, the other particle being the atoms at the grating, and this exchanges a [**virtual photon**](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html) and the momentum is transferred to the solid lattice. In the case of the electron with the wire current the dp/dt will be taken by the wire lattice.

The case of [bremsstrahlung](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBXX5.jpg) has extra electromagnetic vertices. The electron experiments with gratings are at very low energies, and any such radiation is negligible.

Comment: The electron gets deflected , see the double slit  single electron, but the conservation happens with the atoms of the lattice, there is no emmision of a real photon. only of a mathematical virtual that is absorbed creating the interaction

Comment: Really nice answer.